# How come old people (60+) still are contributing to top papers in journals like Nature?

Tags: publications, citations, career-path

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04877-w

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Lander

Eric Lander is 65 years old and he was Science Advisor to the President and was Director of the Office of Science and Technology Policy and yet he published a top article in Nature. How is this still possible to be in the leading edge of research at 65 years old? Is there something I am misunderstanding?

A researcher who doesn't work full-time and does other thing shouldn't be expected to do high-quality research, especially after he switched to a management position.

Comment: "Is there something I am misunderstanding?" It's impossible to tell, since you don't tell us *why* you believe that researchers at the age of 65 should not be expected to do excellent research.

Comment: I mean, 40+ years of experience can't possibly count for anything... I have a staff member significantly older than 65 who continues to produce and publish good work. I've known and worked with many more, and am getting closer to that than I'd like to admit. Frankly, the question is insulting.

Comment: It would probably be wise to have a look at the authors contributions. He wasn't particularly doing the everyday lab and data duties...

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191929/are-there-any-serious-investigations-of-whether-mathematicians-do-their-best-wo/191980#191980) answer to a similar Mathoverflow question.

Comment: @Mark How do you check the contributions and also why is he named last?

Comment: @Sayaman you can find them in the "Author information" section (or other places for other journals, but nowadays, contributions are often listed)

Comment: He is not named last on this paper - if you're not looking closely enough to notice something like that, why should anyone here take you seriously?

Comment: Contrary to rumor, scientists who move into technical management are _not_ given a lobotomy. Instead they now have to grok a broader set of research areas and make connections across more areas.

Comment: Finally, I have an irrefutable excuse for not doing any decent research! I thought I was only going to be ***old*** at 99.

Answer (score 7):

To publish high quality papers, you need a good team, with lots of experience in the topic and in writing papers.

Experience in general is somehow correlated with age, specially for experts in most fields, and particularly for academics (not 100% of course).

In my experience, people overall become better at writing papers with experience and age.

So then there is no reason to discount contributions from senior or even close to retirement academics, they have a lot of accumulated experience, so it should be the other way as you are implying.

Also consider that people that are passionate for science and research are very likely to want to do this literally until the moment they pass away. Personally I really like writing research and its something I would like to do for life.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed a couple of down-votes.
I truly understand the down-voters.
Still, I, personally, think that's a very important question (even though, I do admit, rather irritating).

Recently, I have heard several conversations at my department between the younger colleagues focusing on their inability to understand why the older professors do not retire.

That was a great surprise to me, because I, personally, had noticed the older scientists were the major contributors to the science. I thought that was natural because of their experience.

Though, my younger colleagues didn't seem to think so.

Here's my explanation why it happens.

In my life, I have encountered several professors in what can be called their old ages who were the most knowledgeable people at their respective departments, produced the biggest amount of new ideas at their respective departments and led the most groundbreaking works at their respective departments. Their minds were absolutely sharp, their colleagues would constantly go to them for advice.

And I assumed 2 things.

First, brain - as oppose to the rest of the organs - can get better with age if you keep it trained.

Second, if you are doing science not because you want your salary but because that's the way you live that brings you to harmony with yourself and somehow affects the biochemistry of the brain preventing it from aging.

I'm not going to list all the names of the scientists, I'm talking about for the sake of anonymity. I can only given an example of two scientists who are known publicly.

First is Roger Penrose. He is in his ninetieth. He is full of new ideas. His thinking is clear. His experience is unmatched. At some point, there was even an institute dedicated to the exploration of his ideas!
Second is - to a lesser extent - Leonard Susskind. His thinking is clear and he keeps generating new ideas.

Again, that's not a controversy. That is an absolutely logical consequence of, first, science being your life, second, vast experience. Your body can get tired, but your brain doesn't care about that and keeps generating new ideas as long as you're happy.

And here's why I think the original question is important.

I know that UK universities have a policy that professors should retire at a tender age of 60 or something. There are cases in the US where professors are given to understand that they should start thinking about retirement due to their age.

But, in the light of what I've written above, I think that's wrong. The professors - who want to keep working - should be given everything they want to keep working. They are the greatest treasure of a nation. Their experiences and their potentials to contribute to science are invaluable.

Asking a professor to retire is the worst thing a university can do.

P.S. I understand this answer might be considered an opinion-based. And I will understand if the moderators delete it. Still, I decided to post it because I wasn't allowed to add a comment due to low AcademiaSE score, but I thought the question could lead to an important discussion.

Comment: -1 No offence intended - but jumping from "encounter[ing] several professors" to neurophysiological conclusions ("the brain [,,,] can get better with age if you keep it trained", "somehow affects the biochemistry of the brain preventing it from aging") is unlikely to lead anywhere.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, ok, I agree, I'm being too loose here using the word "concluded" as if I did a rigorous statistical analysis. I should've used the word "assumed" or "suggested". I'll go ahead and edit that. Still, I am not rejecting my assumption. Like I said, I do see that the answer is opinion based and it can be deleted by the moderators.

Comment: I would agree with the sentiment - in fact, I've made a very similar argument (people past the retirement age should be allowed to work) recently elsewhere on SE, but you are speculating quite a lot there. There is a world of difference between "*some* people in academia stay sharp well into the old age, and their experience even gives them an advantage" and "*on average*, academics stay sharper than the general population because they are flexing their brains more". It may well be a subject to selection bias - do all of them stay sharper or only those who keep working and whom you do observe?

Comment: So while I think your perspective is valuable, I have to agree with @JochenGlueck - your answer does not fit the "authoritative source" format very well.

Answer (score 2):

Not everyone can continue to produce good scholarly work into their 70's and beyond but some can. The range of human ability and experience is extremely broad. The fact that you occasionally find people several sigmas beyond the mean is to be expected. Any large population has outliers if it has variability. That's just statistics.

The same is true in other fields as well. Music, perhaps, and art.

Some people are actually more productive as oldsters than as youngsters, perhaps due to opportunity and a developing circle of collaborators (my case). Others work in obscurity on hard problems that only mature in their later years.

One of the reasons that some of us old folks *don't* continue to produce, in fact, is change of interest, not loss of ability.

And, it isn't something that can be especially well predicted for any individual. We are also fragile beings as well as being intelligent ones. A severe concussion or stroke can end a promising career as can several diseases that affect blood flow to the brain. Heart disease and diabetes among them.

And, 65 isn't especially old these days in any case, given modern medicine and technology.